# webview audio is not working properly in my iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Webview audio is not working properly in my iPad ios 8 & ios 9

Below the code:

```
NSString *strURL=@"http://bitcast-a.v1.bom1.bitgravity.com/dinamalar/360view/test8/rear.html";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

Where i made mistake....

Comment: In what way is it not working properly?

Comment: your code is fine,and it works but if you want to hear the audio you have to  click on the "play" button

Comment: Yes I clicked to play but i am not getting song in my iPad..

Comment: where you checked in simulator or in device?

Comment: Hi jithin I ran in My iPad Device ios 8&9

Comment: @fahim parker,its not the way you to talk,if you able to help him ,just do it or else dont tease like this,this is not fair.

Comment: @pps developer,i think it's the problem with autoplay.i tried in iPad simulator,if i click on play button ,then its able to hear the audio.

Comment: I am in chennai...i will try..

Comment: @jithin : I didn't insult.. I was just kidding... I tried and its working in my end..

Comment: @ppsDevelopers : Can you make sure your sound option is ON and not OFF... :(

Answer (score -1):

Add and Import **AVFoundation** framework to your viewcontroller.

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Add the following code in your **viewDidLoad**

```
   NSError *_error = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &_error];
```

Hope it helps.Try it and let me know.